# Spivak, Ch. 14 problem 25d): How do we know that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists if $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation

In problem 25 of chapter 14 of Spivak's *Calculus* we prove the following results in items (a)-(c)

(a) $\int_1^{\infty} x^r dx = -\frac{1}{r+1}$, if $r<-1$

(b) $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx$ does not exist

(c) If $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\int_0^\infty f$ exists then if $0\leq g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$ and $g$ is integrable on each interval $[0,N]$, then $\int_0^{\infty} g$ also exists.

In part (d) we are asked to explain why $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists, with the hint to split the integral at $1$.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Now, $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists because of part $(c)$ since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx<\frac{1}{x^2}$ for all $x$.

The solution manual says the following

> Clearly $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists if $\int_1^{\infty}
>  \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ exists.

How is the above "clearly" true?

Ie, how do we know that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\tag{1}$$ exists?

Note that this is the chapter on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. So far limits, continuity, derivatives, integrals, and the fundamental theorem have been introduced. There are no fancy tools yet to compute the integral above.

In fact, the definition of integrability of a function says it must be bounded on an interval to be integrable on the interval, so we I don't recall there having been any computation of something like $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}$ either.

So, how do we "clearly" know the integral $(1)$ exists?

Comment: Don't you know about $\arctan x$?

Comment: @Cpc Nope. Just a definition of integral in terms of lower and upper sums and the fundamental theorems.

Comment: If you look at the graph it's clearly bounded.

Comment: The integral is the area under the graph.  Also, the derivative of $\arctan x$ is $1/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: The function is certainly bounded: $0 < \frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, hence integrable, and there is no need to know what exact value it is. While $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not, so $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ is problematic as the function is undefined at $x=0$, and indeed the improper integral $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ doesn't converge either.

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted

Answer (score 2):

I attempt to answer this question that "why the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}$" exists.

You may have learned that if a function is continous on an interval [a,b],then it is integrable on this interval.So is is suffice to check the continuity of $f:x\mapsto\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

However, it is rather "clear" that this function is continous on [0,1],then it is "clearly" that f is integrable on [0,1]